# I get an error I'm new to structures and don't know how to solve it

Tags: c, struct, scope, declaration, function-prototypes

I get this error when I try to compile it :

‘struct TMatrix’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration

3 | int InputMatrix (struct TMatrix Matrix);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000
int InputMatrix (struct TMatrix Matrix);
struct TMatrix{
    int L, C;
};
int main() {
    struct TMatrix Matrix;
    InputMatrix(Matrix);
    return 0;
}

int InputMatrix (struct TMatrix Matrix) {
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because you use the type `int InputMatrix (struct TMatrix Matrix)` on the line before you define `struct TMatrix`

Comment: Just declare the struct first, and the functions using it after.

Comment: i did that and now i get this error :



 in function `main':
2.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `InputMatrix'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Heading off the inbound train wreck, once you 'fix' the above problems noted, you're going to discover your `Input` method populates a `TMatrix`, but the caller doesn't get it back. You're passing that `Matrix` by value, not address. That's going to reap a whole lot of work for nothing and the caller's argument will remain as-was before the call.

Comment: Regarding your link-time error, there is no `InputMatrix`; just a promise that there will be one, and that day never came. There is, however, a function called `Input`. Is this your code ?

Comment: I changed and put 

InputMatrix(&Matrix);

also 
int Input (struct TMatrix *Matrix)


but how can i return it?

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the declaration of the structure `struct TMatrix` within the function declaration

```
int InputMatrix (struct TMatrix Matrix);
```

is the parameter list. Outside it this declaration is invisible.

So this structure declaration

```
struct TMatrix{
    int L, C;
    int N;
    int LIN[MAX];
    int COL[MAX];
    float X[MAX];
};
```

declares another structure in the file scope.

You need to exchange the declarations like

```
struct TMatrix{
    int L, C;
    int N;
    int LIN[MAX];
    int COL[MAX];
    float X[MAX];
};

int InputMatrix (struct TMatrix Matrix);
```

Or before the function declaration to place a forward declaration of the structure

```
struct TMatrix;

int InputMatrix (struct TMatrix Matrix);
```

Pay attention to that if you want to change the object of the structure type declared in main then you need to pass it to the function through a pointer to it. Otherwise the function parameter does not make a sense. That is the function should be declared like

```
void InputMatrix( struct TMatrix *Matrix );
```

and in main you should write

```
struct TMatrix Matrix;
InputMatrix( &Matrix );
```

Comment: i did this and how can i return the Matrix?

Comment: @JohnBen What did you do?

Comment: changed it how u did but dont know how to return it

Comment: @JohnBen If you are passing an object of the structure type through a pointer you need not to return it.